# A question about the laplacian of the second fundamental form

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In the article 'Estimates for minimal hypersurfaces' of Schoen Simon and Yau, at (1.16), it asserts that $\triangle h_{ij}= \sum_{k}^{} h_{ijkk}$ .  Why does this equality hold?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your formula in not readable. Please lear Latex basics: `$\Delta h_{ij}=...$`

Comment: It follows by using the Codazzi-Mainardi equations and the identity you get when you switch the order of two covariant derivatives.